# Why is this sum equal to an integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, summation

I participate the stochastic course and we now speak about summable families. There we have the following definition:

> Let $\Omega$ be countable and $a:\Omega\rightarrow \Bbb{R}_+\cup \{\infty\}$ be a map. Then we define $$\sum_\Omega a(\omega):=\sup_{F\subset \Omega, |F|<\infty} \sum_F a(\omega)$$

Now our Prof said that we can consider $\sum_\Omega a(\omega)$ as the integral of $a$ over $\Omega$ to get a better connetion to measure theory afterwards when we speak about Fatou's lemma, Beppo Levi theorem ect. Because all this theorems we have seen with integrals last semester.

But somehow I don't see why this sum is equal to the integral. So I know from measure theory that if we have a simple function $f:\Omega\rightarrow \Bbb{R}_+\cup \{\infty\}$ where $f(\Omega)=\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ finately many then $$\int_\Omega f \ \mathsf d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^nf(b_i)\cdot \mu(\Omega_i)$$ where $\Omega_i=f^{-1}(\{b_i\})$. So but here I don't think that this has to do something with simple functions right?

Therefore I wanted to ask you if someone could explain me why we can see this sum as the integral of $a$ over $\Omega$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a question of measure theory (i.e. Lebesgue integration) rather than stochastic calculus (there is no mention of any stochastic process in the actual question), and hence I edited the tags accordingly.

Comment: okey perfect thanks but could you also help me or not?

Comment: Think of $\Omega$ as a measure space with each point a set of measure $1$. Then that sum is an integral.

Comment: Consider $\mu$ the counting measure, that means $\mu(A) = \mathrm{card}(A).$ It can be shown, when $\Omega$ is countable, that $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$ (the power set of $\Omega$). Then, the definition given coincides with the outer measure. But since $\mu$ can be defined over all subset of $\Omega,$ the outer measure coincides with the measure.

Comment: but why can we take the counting measure. So I mean for me it looks like magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prove that if $\Omega = \{\omega_1, \omega_2, \dots\}$, then $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega}a(\omega) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}a(\omega_i)$.

Now take $\mu$ to be the counting measure on $\Omega$. Really, without loss of generality, you can assume $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$, so you want to prove that $\int_{\mathbb{N}}a\,d\mu = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}a_i$. This is obvious if there exists $N$ such that $a_i = 0$ for $i \geq N$. The general case follows from monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: While this result is true you should really have to had mentioned that you need to show that any ordering of $\Omega$ reaches the same sum because the function $a$ is positive.

Comment: @WilliamM Yes that is a consequence of the first sentence. I left the ordering arbitrary, so proving it would show that the sum is independent of the ordering since $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega}a(\omega)$ is independent of any ordering.